# How to convert char* to array of utf characters and url encode utf (cannot use c++11)?

Tags: c++, get

I am getting from server text (couple words) which contains utf-8 characters (**like Ž,ć**) and another library (which I cannot change storing that in char[], not w_char). I need those words  pass as parameters in URL (to open webview on mobile client). I tried urlencode(function which I have which works fine on ascii) but it encodes as ascii and Javascript cannot decode that back to use. How to convert char* to array of utf characters and url encode utf ?

```
std::string urlencode(const std::string &c)
{

    std::string escaped="";
    int max = c.length();
    for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        if ( (48 <= c[i] && c[i] <= 57) ||//0-9
            (65 <= c[i] && c[i] <= 90) ||//abc...xyz
            (97 <= c[i] && c[i] <= 122) || //ABC...XYZ
            (c[i]=='~' || c[i]=='!' || c[i]=='*' || c[i]=='(' || c[i]==')' || c[i]=='\'')
            )
        {
            escaped.append( &c[i], 1);
        }
        else
        {
            escaped.append("%");
            escaped.append( char2hex(c[i]) );//converts char 255 to string "ff"
        }
    }
    return escaped;
}

std::string char2hex( char dec )
{
    char dig1 = (dec&0xF0)>>4;
    char dig2 = (dec&0x0F);
    if ( 0<= dig1 && dig1<= 9) dig1+=48;    //0,48inascii
    if (10<= dig1 && dig1<=15) dig1+=97-10; //a,97inascii
    if ( 0<= dig2 && dig2<= 9) dig2+=48;
    if (10<= dig2 && dig2<=15) dig2+=97-10;

    std::string r;
    r.append( &dig1, 1);
    r.append( &dig2, 1);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw ASCII codes, use `'0'` instead of `48` and `'9'` instead of `57`. It will be much more readable

Comment: Instead of `48` or `97`, please use `'0'` and `'a'`; your team mates will thank you.

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes and @sasha.sochka -+1. But since when common sense prevail over coder's sense?

Comment: If you're on Windows, use MultibyteToWideChar which can convert utf8 to utf16 and InternetCanonicalizeUrl to encode url. If not, I'm sure, unix/linux do have similar APIs. Also, there's ICU (http://site.icu-project.org/) library which can do all things you can possibly imagine with unicode (including the conversions and I believe url encoding). Also there are small libraries which can perform conversions for you. One of them is utfcpp: (http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)